# Don't wait for function to end before refresh template

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following checkbox in the view that calls a function in the component ts that do some heavy calculation and save some values in my database through an HTTP call.

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="checkOption($event.target.checked)" [checked]="value === true" />
```

here's the function:

```
checkOption(value: boolean): void {
    this.value = value;
    // a function that takes too much time to execute
    this.function1();
}
```

The checkbox doesn't get checked (or unchecked) before `this.function1();` ends the execution.
Is there a way to refresh the checkbox the moment the `this.value = value;` gets executed ?

Comment: You could e.g. wrap your heavy function inside a `setTimeout()` without a time param. This delays the execution to the end of the next event loop cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `change detection strategy` and run `detectChanges` function as soon as you update this.value variable